# Why does my Samsung Galaxy S crash ("Not enough space in music database") when sorting by artist?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, music-player

Had my Samsung Galaxy S for a week or so, and my new micro-SD card arrived a few days ago, loaded all my music onto it, listened to various albums no problem.

Now when I go into the built-in Music Player app and select the "Artists" tab at the top, Music Player closes with a "Not enough space in music database" error in the notification bar with a red warning triangle sign.

All the other tabs (All, Playlists, Albums & Genres) work with no problem, but as soon as I hit the Artists tab it crashes out. It's a 32GB SD-card with about 25GB of music on it, the internal SD card is almost empty with no music on it at all. On the PC I'm a SqueezePlayer and Last.Fm user, so I'm pretty sure all my tags are setup right (Last.FM lets you know in your feed if you've got incorrect artist/track info, and SqueezePlayer lives or dies by the quality of your tagging).

Searching for this on the web, all I can find is other people with various sized music collections and SD-cards (8, 16 & 32GB) all having this problem and the only suggestions are to download different music apps from the Market. No one seems to have a real solution. That can't be right can it? I previously had an HTC Magic Android phone with a full 8GB micro-SD and much of the same music with no problems playing.

There must be some way to get the built-in music player app working properly? Does anyone know what file/where is this database and whether wiping/clearing it would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this thread on the Vibrant section of the XDA Devs forum: [Not Enough Space in Music Database?](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=729315&page=2) (pretty sure the Vibrant is a US carrier-specific version of the Galaxy, with this weird obsession US networks seem to have for making up alternative names for devices).

> Maybe it has something to do with how
>   the app handles various artists and/or
>   unknown artists.
>
> I added all my music, then deleted
>   tracks from various artist albums
>   until it worked again. I then put back
>   the various artist album track and it
>   didn't work, as expected.
>
> I thought this was artist based, but
>   when I got it working again--by
>   deleting the track mentioned
>   above--and then added a track for a
>   various artist album by an artist that
>   already existed, the app crashed too.
>
> I then thought it might be song based.
>   So I removed that song and then added
>   a set of songs. However, it
>   unexpectantly worked.
>
> The difference with the set of songs
>   added above is that they weren't part
>   of a various artist album. They were a
>   new artist, but the main album artist
>   wasn't Various with a Contributing
>   artist of the actual artist name.
>   Instead, the Album Artist was the
>   artist name and the contributing
>   artist was left blank (or had the same
>   name).
>
> So, it is that the music app doesn't
>   understand how to handle various
>   artist albums?

Plugged SD card into my PC, did a search for files named *.mp3 with "various" in the artist tag, moved all of them off the card. Plugged card back into Galaxy again, waiting for media indexing to finish, I can now view the Artists column without the app crashing. Still can't Search in the app without crashing, but I have a few more compilation type albums so will try spotting and removing all of them to see if it helps.

**Update Nov 2010**: The Music player included in the official Samsung Froyo (Android 2.2) update, seems to have fixed this problem, or at least made it so that I can have the majority of my tracks on the phone without this problem showing up.